# Как вытащить представителя активити и передать в другой класс android?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, context, singleton

Сейчас пытаюсь сделать три вещи, сохранение, запись в sharedpreferences и переход на другое активити по intent. Если я правильно понимаю то для всех этих действий нужно использовать контекст активити на котором мы находимся. Я хочу сделать эти все действия в отдельном классе и поэтому мне нужно как-то передать активити в этот класс. Этот класс является синглтоном, и в нем я хочу реализовать все эти действия. Есть насколько я понял три варианта получения данных о активити:

1. `getApplicationContext()`
2. `getBaseContext()`
3. `getContext()`

Я так понимаю что результат одной из этих функций нужно передать в конструктор моего синглтона. Вот например есть запись и чтение в настройки из обычной активити:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("id", 0);
editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("id", value);
editor.apply();
```

или вот чтение:

```
sp = Objects.requireNonNull(Activity.this).getSharedPreferences("id", 0);
String value= sp.getString("id", "");
```

или вот переход на другое активити при помощи интента:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(First_activity.this, Second_activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

но эти все методы можно использовать только на активити а чтобы использовать в другом классе, то нужно что-то передать в класс чтобы все заработало. Уже весь день сижу и ковыряюсь но так и не смог сделать то что нужно.

Comment: Все эти методы можно использовать вне активити. context.getSharedPreferences и context.startActivity(intent) попробуйте. Тут можно пробрасывать контекст в конструктор класса/метода, можно еще сделать глобальный доступ к нему https://stackoverflow.com/a/37969605/4829111

Comment: да но мне нужно какое-то значение для context задать, или нет? я так понял что нужно присвоить для этой переменной путем передачи в конструктор контекста и дальше уже с ней работать

Comment: По поводу контекста, имеется определенная библиотека, которая позволяет постоянно получать контексте, вне зависимости что за элемент перед нами

Comment: @danilshik, вы имеете в виду что можно тащить из любого класса контекст при помощи библиотеки? если это так то какая именно библиотека за это отвечает? потому-что я никак не могу решить проблему с доступом к настройкам и переходом на другое активити через интент

Comment: Да, только я вспомнить не могу как она называется

Comment: может можно как-то без библиотеки справится?

Comment: Я вам отвечаю по поводу контекста: Это библиотека AppCtx https://github.com/LouisCAD/Splitties/tree/master/appctx

Comment: спасибо большое за ссылку, у меня вроде получилось передать context не знаю хорошая ли это идея передавать контекст из каждой активити, но теперь вроде все сохраняется в памяти устройства, только осталось сделать переход на другую активити)